# Ajax Calendar Extender, client side event shows previous day

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to store the selected date of an Ajax Calendar Extender control in a hidden field. I used OnClientDateSelectionChanged to set it.

However, when I select 02/22/2015, the selected date in the script shows as 02/21/2015. I added setting the textbox's value using this selected value, to test it, and it shows as 02/21/2015.

It also sets the value of the hidden field as "Feb 21 19:00:00 EST 2015" which throws an error when trying to convert to datetime.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbStartDate" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFrom" ImageUrl="Calendar.gif" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" 
    ID="calStartDate"
    Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    TargetControlID="tbStartDate"
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged= "startDateChanged"
    PopupButtonID="imgFrom" /> 


function startDateChanged(sender, args) {
    var hfStartDate = document.getElementById('<%=hfStartDate.ClientID %>');
    var selectedDate = sender._selectedDate;
    hfStartDate.value = selectedDate;
    sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
}
```